# Tomcat 8 + Spring - Double request error

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, request

I am running a Spring production app in a Tomcat 8 environment.

In my app, we have a shopping cart, and a business constraint is that you cannot add the same item more than once. The add process is by ajax

I do validate this previously making a request to know if that item exists in my shopping cart due to the client may acumulate the product in the same items (i.e: iPhone SE - Quantity: 2); which is different to have the same item in two rows.

Well, rarely the item is being added twice (two rows), and looking in my database actuator data, the item is added once after another:

- 1st at 2017-11-27 10:25:10.867
- 2nd at 2017-11-27 10:25:10.950

So then I've looked the Tomcat Access Log, which prints all the requests and found that the POST request is being called twice at same time.

```
172.31.10.222 - - [27/Nov/2017:10:25:11 -0300] "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 34
172.31.30.32 - - [27/Nov/2017:10:25:11 -0300] "POST /shopping-cart/041963/item HTTP/1.1" 200 97
172.31.10.222 - - [27/Nov/2017:10:25:11 -0300] "GET /articles?start=0&length=100&no_count=true&_=1511788857988 HTTP/1.1" 200 803
172.31.30.32 - - [27/Nov/2017:10:25:11 -0300] "POST /shopping-cart/041963/item HTTP/1.1" 200 97
172.31.10.222 - - [27/Nov/2017:10:25:11 -0300] "GET /articles?start=0&length=100&no_count=true&_=1511784298835 HTTP/1.1" 200 90
172.31.10.222 - - [27/Nov/2017:10:25:11 -0300] "POST /shopping-cart/018150/item HTTP/1.1" 200 97
172.31.30.32 - - [27/Nov/2017:10:25:11 -0300] "POST /shopping-cart/060931/item HTTP/1.1" 200 97
```

The one which is duplicated at same time is `172.31.30.32 - - [27/Nov/2017:10:25:11 -0300] "POST /shopping-cart/041963/item HTTP/1.1" 200 97` which is at the same time of the database actuator data `10:25:10.867`

I've already disabled the submit button and tried to "hack" it, like clicking many times, or submitting the form via the enter key many times, but cannot reproduce it.

Anyone has a clue of what can be going on?

**UPDATE**

I'm adding the js code executed when form is submitted:

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();

    var formData = $("#addItemForm").serializeObject();
    var clientCode = $("#clientCode").val();

    blockUI();

    $.ajax({
        url : $("#ctx").val() + "/shopping-cart/" + clientCode + "/item",
        method : "POST",
        data : JSON.stringify(formData),
        contentType : "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        cache : false
    }).done(function(data) {
        $("#addItemModal").modal("hide");
    }).fail(function(xhr) {
        handleAjaxErrorMessage(xhr);
    }).always(function() {
        unblockUI();
    });
});
```

Comment: Perhaps the user is using a different browser than you, and that is why you cannot reproduce the problem. If might be failing JavaScript code on the browser the user is using. Without showing us the JavaScript code, it is however impossible to say what might be wrong.

Comment: any chance you have some client side retry if request failed or timed out code that executes the same Ajax POST action?

Comment: How can you click the submit button multiple times after you have disabled it?

Comment: @Andreas I've tried in the main browsers and also in tablets. Javascript of my own code is not triggering more than once

Comment: @BorisDaich I thought of that but in my logs at that time I have no error or trace of the request failing.

Comment: @BheshGurung I have disabled it by javascript. When I say that I click the submit button multiples times, I'm trying to say that I try to click the button multiple times, like if I can hack the "disabling" because of velocity.

Comment: There's a lot going on here that we cannot see, and too much missing context for anyone to be able to even guess at a possible cause.  You are going to have to reproduce the issue while watching the network traffic with Wireshark and monitoring the client Javascript with the browser's debugging tools.  I'd bet the problem is a logic error in the Ajax Javascript that has nothing to do with the user submitting the request twice.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you can provide your javascript code. It is possible to submit form twice sometimes. Try these to prevent that:

**Using .on:**

Disable button listener after click and add it again onsuccess or error using [stopImmediatePropagation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/).

```
   var checkoutSubmit = function(e){

        $.ajax({      
         ....
          success: function(data){
            $('#checkoutButton').one('click', checkoutSubmit);
          },
          error: function(){}
        });

        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        return false;
    }

    $('#checkoutButton').one('click', checkoutSubmit);
```

**Disable key using:**

```
onClick="this.disabled=true;"
```

Comment: I've added the js code in the original post. One thing to highlight again is that this happens rarely. Is not like always the item is being submitted twice.